# Смена span на активном классе

Tags: jquery

[image]

Как оформить код что бы при нажатии на любой пункт  меню  удалялся спан с крестиком а добавлялся в место него спан с зеленой галочкой, и что б при переключении менялось как положено. Только открытый пункт меню должен отображать галочку.

```
$("h3:first").addClass("active");
$("p:not(:first)").hide();

$("h3").click(function () {
    $('.accordion').toggleClass('#two');

    $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow")
        .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active").addClass('h3 > span');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас какой-то страшный код, все можно сделать гораздо проще, достаточно вешать дополнительный класс выделенному пункту меню, соответственно завязать на этот класс видимость элементов с крестиком и галочкой.

Comment: Подскажите как 'завязать' класс с элементами ?

Comment: ну скажем
.control {background: url("cancel.png")}
.active .control {background: url("accept.png")}